# Adding methods to template specialization

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated C++ class that exposes a number of methods, e.g

```
template<int X, int Y>
class MyBuffer {
public:
    MyBuffer<X,Y> method1();
};
```

Now, I want to expose additional methods to this class if X == Y. I have done this by subclassing MyBuffer,

```
template<int X>
class MyRegularBuffer : public MyBuffer<X,X> {
public:
    MyRegularBuffer method2();
};
```

Now, the problem is that I want to be able to do e.g.

```
MyRegularBuffer<2> buf = ...
MyRegularBuffer<2> otherBuf = buf.method1().method2();
```

But I am not sure how to accomplish this. I tried to think of copy constructors, conversion operators, etc, but my C++ skills are unfortunately a bit rusty.

EDIT: I should add that creation of these objects is relatively cheap (and also, it won't happen a lot), which means it would be OK to do something like this:

```
MyRegularBuffer<2> buf = ...
MyRegularBuffer<2> temp = buf.method1(); // Implicit conversion
MyRegularBuffer<2> otherBuf = temp.method2();
```

The question is then, how can I define the conversion like that. The conversion operator needs to be in MyBuffer, I think, but I want it to be available only if X==Y.

Comment: Completely incomprehensible. For  example, you talk about "the conversion operator", but there is none. Post some real code .

Comment: @Neil, I think the user has asked a genuine question to the best of their ability. And I think I understand it somewhat.

Comment: @Aaron In that case, please share your understanding.

Comment: @Neil, see my answer. The important line in the user's question is "buf.method1().method2();"   'buf' is one of the special cases where X==Y, and hence it is possible to call method2(). But 'buf.method1().method2()' would not work as desired because while we 'know' it's special, the compiler does not.  A useful analogy might be to consider Circles and Ellipses. Some Ellipses are Circles, but the compiler isn't always know this and won't expose getRadius().

Whereas ImmutableEllipse<double major, double minor>, with appropriate specialization for ImmutableCircle, would solve this problem.

Comment: @Neil, sorry I see that the template arguments fell away. Don't know why. About the conversion operator, I was merely asking if that was a possible way to go, and if so, how to write it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need a separate class to represent the special behaviour. Partial specialization allows you to treat some of the MyBuffer <X,Y> cases specially and give them extra methods.

Keep your original declaration of MyBuffer<X,Y> and add this:

```
template<int Y>
class MyBuffer<Y, Y> {
public:
    MyBuffer<Y,Y> method1();
    MyBuffer<Y,Y> method2();
};

MyBuffer<1,2> m12; m12.method2(); // compile fail, as desired, as it doesn't have such a method because 1 != 2
MyBuffer<2,2> m22; m22.method2(); // compile success
```

**Edit:** my final lines weren't very useful after all, as pointed out by Georg in the comments, so I've deleted them.

Comment: The only downside is that method1() has to be re-implemented in MyBuffer<Y,Y>, or else the compiler will complain about an unknown method when you try to call MyBuffer<Y,Y>::method1(). AFAIK, there is no way to have MyBuffer<Y,Y>::method1() delegate its implementation to MyBuffer<X,Y>::method1() without specifying different template parameters where X != Y.

Comment: Deriving from `MyBuffer` wouldn't work - it doesn't know of the derived class and thus can't return the appropriate type from `method1()`.

Comment: @Georg, I do not understand. Can you be more specific about which line will fail? I have compiled my code and it works. But I must admit I copied the very last line incorrectly about "class MyRegularBuffer". Will update now.

Comment: @Remy, that is interesting and I've been struggling with that. If anybody has ideas, let us know. Copying and pasting, or otherwise, the code for method1() would certainly be inconvenient.

Comment: I'm addressing your *convenience* snippet: `method1()` is implemented in `MyBuffer<int,int>`, which doesn't know about the classes deriving from it. Ergo code like `MyRegularBuffer<1> a, b; a = b.method1();` could not work - you'd have to use CRTP to give the base class sufficient information (i've shown how in my answer).

Comment: Ah yes. A typedef that could be templated would be handy, or something else to give a convenient name .

I just tried to downvote my own answer. Yours is better. But I'm not allowed to (down)vote my own answer.

Here's an (ugly) hack that should work:  "template<int X> struct MyRegular { typedef MyBuffer<X,X> Buffer; }; " Which could then be used as "MyRegular<2>::Buffer m2;"

Comment: I guess this is the best solution, although I can't really understand why I couldn't add methods like that without reimplementing the whole class. But I guess the compiler struggles enough as it is :)

Comment: @Aaron: factoring the shared methods in a base class MyBufferBase<X,Y>, of which both MyBuffer<X,Y> and the specialisation MyBuffer<Y,Y> derive, should do the trick. (MyBuffer<X,Y> won't contain any methods as all are defined in MyBufferBase)

Comment: I do not know if using template specialization to define MyBuffer<Y,Y> would allow for derivation, but I do agree that MyBuffer<X,Y>::method1()'s code could be refactored out, such as into a standalone function that MyBuffer<X,Y>::method1() and MyBuffer<Y,Y>::method1() can both call.

Answer (score 7):

I'd go for [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) here:

```
template<int X, int Y, class Derived>
struct MyBufferBase {
    // common interface:
    Derived& method1() { return *static_cast<Derived*>(this); }
};

template<int X, int Y>
struct MyBuffer : MyBufferBase<X, Y, MyBuffer<X,Y> > {
    // basic version
};

template<int X> 
struct MyRegularBuffer : MyBufferBase<X, X, MyRegularBuffer<X> > {
    // extended interface:
    MyRegularBuffer& method2() { return *this; }
};
```

Comment: I would have marked as answer if I could have given the mark to more than one answer, but right now Aaron McDaid's solution actually falls out quite well, since my methods are quite thin (it is a wrapper class).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do what you want if `method1` and `method2` return a reference to `*this`. Otherwise, you're going to need to either do a conversion, or make `method1` virtual.

Comment: Even if method1() returns this you still can't call method2() from its return value, because method2() is not part of the interface of MyBuffer<X,Y>.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the virtual method approach? I am not sure I got that... The problem I'm facing is the contract, the implementation would be the same (the object are identical in memory if X==Y, so I could just do a reinterpretation).

Comment: wilhelmtell, yes, exactly what I meant. You were quicker :)

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to have a `MyRegularBuffer::method1` that calls `MyBuffer::method1`, then a way to convert the resultant `MyBuffer<X,X>` into a `MyRegularBuffer<X>`:

```
template<int X>
class MyRegularBuffer : public MyBuffer<X,X> 
{
public:

  MyRegularBuffer<X>()
  {}

  MyRegularBuffer<X>(MyBuffer<X,X>)
  {
    // copy fields, or whatever
  }

  MyRegularBuffer<X> method2();

  MyRegularBuffer<X> method1()
  {
    MyRegularBuffer<X> ret(MyBuffer<X,X>::method1());
    return(ret);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is a good idea, but in my case it doesn't add anything to @Aaron McDaid's solution, in that I have to implement method1 again (method1 is actually a number of methods).